# How to access django development server on VM virtual box from actual computer?

Tags: django, virtualbox

[Virtual box settingimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74yD9.jpg)I have my actual laptop which has virtual box installed. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 as a virtual machine and I installed Django on the virtual machine and am testing my app so I did `python manage.py runserver` and I can access the app by visiting `127.0.0.1:8000` from my VM. However, if I go to `127.0.0.1:8000` from the actual computer (not the VM), it says

> chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8000

I added ip address of host computer on allowed hosts on settings.py file but still its now working. If I did `manage.py runserver 192.0.2.15:8000` on vm where 192.0.2.15 is ip address of vm, it gives error that ip address can't be assigned to.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think your question is more appropriate for https://superuser.com/.

Comment: You could also try to run the dev server with this command: `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: I couldnot access django server by doing manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. @ Paolo